Is it possible to access values of tags from the current element of a foreach loop in Overpass QL
I am trying to get data of places with their population via OSM.
The first step was simply to get all nodes, ways and relations with a place and population value within the desired area. But I noticed that some places had both a node and a way referring to the same place. Now Im trying to find a way to detect those nodes and remove them from the result set. My plan was to loop through all the polygons (closed ways) and get any nodes within the current polygon that has the same name as that polygon. The problem is that I don't see how I access the values of the tags of the element Im currently looping through. Is this possible or should I tackle this in a different way?
Note: the code inside the foreach loop isn't valid, but its to show what I would like to do. Its also missing some code from the full problem, so it can focus on just the foreach problem
[out:json][timeout:25];

// Define the area of interest
rel(2184073);
map_to_area->.searchArea;

// Get all closed ways (polygons)
way["place"]["population"](area.searchArea)(if:is_closed()) -> .polygonAreas;

foreach.polygonAreas->.polyArea
{
  node["place"]["population"](area.polyArea)(if: t["place"] == .polyArea["place"]);
  out;
}

